# XMLStreamException because of & in xml

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

I want to parse an xml file to a java object.

I use **XMLInputFactory** library for doing this.

```
XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filepath);
eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(in);
```

What can I do if I have an '&' in my text e.g.: `<example>I like programming & football</example>`

I always get an error message:

> javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3608,52]
>   Message: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(Unknown Source)

I know why the error is happening. The parser wants to look for &amp, &.., ... But I don't know how to escape the error.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to fix the XML. If you are on Linux or have Cygwin, it's easy: sed will do it in a one-liner.

Comment: Try `inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, true);` Also make sure to set the right encoding for your reader, something like `inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(in,"UTF-8");`

Comment: @dehlen How would "coalescing adjacent character data" help to avoid a parser exception on an ampersand that hasn't been escaped using `&amp;`?

Comment: @dehlen: that doesn't help either.

Comment: @lauen: I am using windows

Comment: It sounds like you want to parse a non-XML file. In that case you will need a non-XML parser. I would recommend using XML instead, it will make your life much easier.

Comment: @MichaelKay It happens more often than the W3C boffins would like to think: the label "XML" is slapped on to something that isn't XML. And then the hue-and-cry begins. - I think that OP's data is badly written XML. So is there a way out?

Comment: @laune: you are right, the data was badly written I solved the problem by contacting my customer. Can you write an answer so I can except it?

Comment: @posk Done. Send the customer my compliments ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appearance of an unescaped (as `&amp;`) ampersand in an XML file violates the basic rule of how XML files have to be written. (`&lt;` and `&gt;` are other obvious examples.)

Any XML producer should make sure to adhere to the W3C spec for XML.

If you have to patch a badly written file *and if & is not used for introducing HTML entities at all* you might try a patch via sed or some similar utility.